# How to calculate balance of accounts by joining 2 tables in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```cs
_dbContext.CashVoucherDetails
    .Where(x => x.CreationDate.Date >= From.Date && x.CreationDate.Date <= To.Date && x.Type == Common.TransactionType.CPV && x.CompanyCode == BranchCode)
    .GroupBy(v => new { v.AccountCode, v.AccountDescription, v.CompanyCode })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        AccountDescription = g.Key.AccountDescription,
        AccountCode = g.Key.AccountCode,
        Payment = g.Sum(x => x.outer.DebitAmount),
        Balance = _dbContext.CashVoucherDetails.Where(x => x.CreationDate.Date <= To.Date && x.CompanyCode == g.Key.CompanyCode && x.AccountCode == g.Key.AccountCode)
                  .Sum(x => x.DebitAmount - x.CreditAmount) +
                  _dbContext.SaleDetails.Where(x => x.CreationDate.Date <= To.Date && x.CompanyCode == g.Key.CompanyCode && x.AccountCode == g.Key.AccountCode)
                  .Sum(x => x.DebitAmount - x.CreditAmount) //<------ Issue HERE. Calculate balance take too much time.
    })
```

I want to find balances of accounts so the payments details in 2 tables, I need to join those tables and (Debit - Credit) all entries. This query works fine but takes much time. Can anyone tell, how I can optimize this query so it will take less time to calculate balances.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to check the generated SQL, run it against the database and see if there is something what can be optimized.

Comment: Is there any other way to write nested query?

Comment: Maybe. You need to figure out the SQL itself first (and indexes).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. Balances are calculated separately and then joined. If query is still slow, you have to check execution plan and create appropriate indexes.

```cs
var saleDetails = dbContext.SaleDetails
  .Where(x => x.CreationDate.Date <= To.Date)
  .GroupBy(x => new { x.AccountCode, x.CompanyCode })
  .Select(g => new 
  {
      g.Key.AccountCode, 
      g.Key.CompanyCode,
      Balance = g.Sum(x => x.DebitAmount - x.CreditAmount)
  });

var voucherDeatils = _dbContext.CashVoucherDetails
    .Where(x => x.CreationDate.Date >= From.Date && x.CreationDate.Date <= To.Date && x.Type == Common.TransactionType.CPV && x.CompanyCode == BranchCode)
    .GroupBy(v => new { v.AccountCode, v.AccountDescription, v.CompanyCode })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.AccountDescription,
        g.Key.AccountCode,
        g.Key.CompanyCode,
        Payment = g.Sum(x => x.outer.DebitAmount),
        Balance = g.Sum(x => x.DebitAmount - x.CreditAmount)
    });

var result = 
    from v in voucherDeatils
    join s in saleDetails on new { v.AccountCode, v.CompanyCode } equals new { s.AccountCode, s.CompanyCode } into gj
    from s in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        v.AccountDescription
        v.AccountCode, 
        v.CompanyCode,
        v.Payment,
        Balance = b.Balance + ((double?)s.Balance) ?? 0
    };
```